# React Native newbie. Using XCode for the native iOS part in /iOS. What do I use for javascript in root folder? What's a best-practice workflow?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, ide, workflow

Confused as any newbie would be!

I am a React Native newbie. Following a tutorial I created a project. I can use XCode to open the native iOS project in /iOS. What do I use for the javascript files in the root folder? Should I use a second editor for js - i.e. one of the standard js editors (Atom, vi etc).  What is the best-practice workflow? Or can I accomplish everything with one editor. Advice, recommendations would be most appreciated.

CLARIFICATIOINS:
To clarify my question, take the following sample project:

I want to write a react native app which opens to a table view i.e. list screen with multiple items in a list screen. When you pick one item in the list the app navigates to a details screen. Suppose the list screen is React Native and the details screen is Native iOS.  I  can code up the list screen using VSCode in React Native js. And then I can code the native details screen in XCode. So for the native part I can open XCode and create a fresh project. What kind of project should this be? Should it be an IOS App or am IOS framework/library? Perhaps a main app as the AppDelegate and a test harness, and a framework/library for the one View Controller screen I will need to import into my React Native project? And then how do I run this to test and debug it out end to end in the simulator? I can possibly correct and live reload the React native portion, but suppose I want to update the iOS portion, what step do I need to go back to? etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very common to do your coding work directly inside XCode. XCode is more of a place to organize your project/environment/builds/signing etc...
Instead you should be writing all of your code inside the editor of your choice. The standard workflow would be:

- Create project on command line
- Use your editor of choice for coding. I use VSCode.
- in your editor, open your project folder that you just created
- use XCode for running the ios emulator and super specific iOS tasks
- All Android specific work can easily be done in VSCode (you don't ever actually need to use Android Studio)

Comment: Hello Maxwell thank you for your response. This clarifies the first part (and I will use VSCode for the javascript react native portion, thank you) I am still not clear about the second part - i.e overall workflow.

Comment: I think you might have a bit of a misunderstanding of how the React Native workflow is. It's actually a lot simpler than what I feel you're picturing. The app you've described can very easily be made entirely within React Native javascript code. There's no need for any native iOS work there. If you're thinking about making things different for each OS, look into the React Native class 'Platform'.